# change directory from string

Tags: bash, path, cygwin, cd

Here is the problem. I have a bash script which getting the path from php script. But it can't change directory to returning path;

```
function go_to_path
{
  path=$(php myscript)
  echo $path; # is totally okay, printing expected value 
  cd $path; # err -> no such file or directory. Directory is obviously exists
}
```

that stuff does not work too

```
eval cd $path
echo $(cd $path)
cd "$path"
```

I am running bash via cygwin on windows

Comment: Remove blank before and after `=`.

Comment: Set variable in quotes: `"$path"`

Comment: it's on "does not work" list

Comment: Put the function in a shell script and run `bash -x` on it and post output. Would also likely help to get exact output rather than seeing your comments of it.

Comment: Of course it won't work if the path you get from the script is a windows path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ohh my. So I guess I haven't compose my question correctly. The path value is taken from dynamic algorithm. Which just echo returning value. The solution was easy, instead of echoing value I should exit it. I mean exit the script with path value.

Answer (score 4):

This worked fine for me:

```
function go_to_path
{
    path="/home/arnon/scripts"
    echo $path
    cd $path
}
ls
go_to_path
ls
```

It won't work if 'path' contains '~' (for instance on this example: `path="~/scripts"`) cause that's a shell interpreted character, and not really part of the directory's name.

It also won't work if 'path' is relative to a directory that is not the directory you're running this script from. (In other words if 'php myscript' is returning a relative path make sure the relativity applies to the location your bash script is run from).

Comment: php script returns absolute directory

Comment: This also won't work if the path contains spaces, other whitespace, or globbing characters. You should double quote the variables when used as an argument to a command, like `echo "$path"`, `cd "$path"`, etc

Comment: if I just copypaste return value from the script change directory is working as expected. path value is completely legit

Comment: Does it work if you write the legit path manually in the script?